# mySQL 5.7 - calculated column / trigger function

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need to do simple math in mySQL table.

I have table payment_tbl
with fields: normal, penalty, refund and trying to add filed outstanding which will be normal + penalty + refund?

Code for payment_tbl:

```
create table payment_tbl (
payment_id INT (10) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
payment_amount decimal (5,2) not null, 
payment_date DATE not null,
normal decimal (5,2) not null,
penalty decimal (5,2) not null,
refund decimal (5,2) not null,
out decimal (5,2));

INSERT into payment_tbl (
payment_amount, 
payment_date, 
normal, 
penalty,
refund)
values ('5.55', '2015-05-05', '5.55','0', '0');
```

So I am trying to have the column out as sum of all three payments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the documentation for [generated columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html):

```
CREATE TABLE payment_tbl(
    payment_id INT (10) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    payment_amount decimal (5,2) not null,
    payment_date DATE not null,
    normal decimal (5,2) not null,
    penalty decimal (5,2) not null,
    refund decimal (5,2) not null,
    `out` decimal (5,2) AS (normal+penalty+refund)
);
```

I modified the definition of the `out` column to be the sum of the 3 other columns. You don't need a trigger.

Comment: I did try similar and yours and got the same error:ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the r
ight syntax to use near 'out decimal (5,2) AS (normal+penalty+refund)
)' at line 8

Comment: OUT is a MySQL reserved keyword. You must enclose it in backticks. See my updated answer above. See: [Reserved keywords in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use on of thise Query to add the COLUMN. If you use the PERSISTENT Query you can also add an INDEX on this COLUMN.

```
ALTER TABLE payment_tbl
ADD COLUMN `out` DECIMAL(5,2) AS ( normal + penalty + refund)  VIRTUAL;

ALTER TABLE payment_tbl
ADD COLUMN `outp` DECIMAL(5,2) AS ( normal + penalty + refund)  PERSISTENT;
```